# Need help using Selenium-Chromedriver and Python3, browser automation

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, browser-automation

I would like to print each name of every merchant on this page. I tried this:

```py
browser.get('https://www.trovaprezzi.it/televisori-lcd-plasma/prezzi-scheda-prodotto/lg_oled_cx3?sort=prezzo_totale')

Names = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='merchant_name']")

for span in Names:
    
print(span.text)
```

However, when I run the code, it prints an huge empty space without any word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 You need to get `alt` attribute to get a seller name

2 You need to use waits.

3 Check your indentation when you print a list values.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait


browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/snap/bin/chromium.chromedriver')

browser.get('https://www.trovaprezzi.it/televisori-lcd-plasma/prezzi-scheda-prodotto/lg_oled_cx3?sort=prezzo_totale')
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".merchant_name_and_logo img")))


names = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".merchant_name_and_logo img")

for span in names:
    print(span.get_attribute("alt"))
```

Prints:

```
Climaconvenienza
Shopdigit
eBay
ePrice
Onlinestore
Shoppyssimo
Prezzo forte
eBay
eBay
eBay
eBay
eBay
eBay
Yeppon
Showprice
Galagross
Sfera Ufficio
Climaconvenienza
Di Lella Shop
Shopdigit
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `span.text` please try getting the "value" attribute there

```
Names = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='merchant_name']")

for span in Names:
    
    print(span..get_attribute("value"))
```

Also, don't forget adding some wait / delay before

```
Names = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='merchant_name']")
```

Answer (score 0):

Selenium removed `find_elements_by_*` in version `4.3.0`. See the CHANGES: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/a4995e2c096239b42c373f26498a6c9bb4f2b3e7/py/CHANGES

```
* Deprecated find_element_by_* and find_elements_by_* are now removed (#10712)
```

So instead of `find_elements_by_xpath(XPATH)`, use `find_elements("xpath", XPATH)`. And instead of `find_elements_by_css_selector(CSS_SELECTOR)`, use `find_elements("css selector", CSS_SELECTOR)`.

Here's a full script to print all the merchants listed:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.trovaprezzi.it/televisori-lcd-plasma/prezzi-scheda-prodotto/lg_oled_c3?sort=prezzo_totale")
elements = driver.find_elements("css selector", ".merchant_name_and_logo span")
for element in elements:
    print(element.get_attribute("innerText"))
driver.quit()
```